# UpdatePanel Only Updates on Initial Partial PostBack

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sitefinity, jquery-cookie

I have a Master Page that has various placeholders that loads user controls for different content.  A header would be one and the main page content another.  Within the main content user control, it loads various other user controls based on what page is needing displayed.

**Master Page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true" CodeBehind="Admin.Master.cs" Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.Admin" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SitefinityWebApp.Model.Session" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <!-- start of header -->
        <section id="header">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cph_header" runat="server" />
        </section>

        <!-- Site  Content -->
        <section id="contentWrapper">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cph_content" runat="server" />
        </section>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The following page gets loaded into content**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CorpPendingApproval.ascx.cs" Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.userctrls.Admin.Dashboard.Corporate.CorpPendingApproval" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="PendingApprovalList" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_currentPage" runat="server" value="0" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_totalResults" runat="server" value="0" />

        <h2>Pending Approvals</h2>
        <div class="corporateAdminPagination">
            <a ID="topPageBack" class="leftArrow" runat="server" onserverclick="PageBack"></a>
            <asp:Label ID="topCurrentPageInfo" Text="" runat="server" />
            <a ID="topPageForward" class="rightArrow" runat="server" onserverclick="PageForward"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Table Start -->
        <table class="corporateAdminPendingApprovals" cellspacing="0">

            <!-- Table Heading -->

            <!-- Example Binding Setup -->
            <asp:Repeater ID="LowPriority" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr class="pendingApprovalListItem" 
                        <!-- Repeater Bindings Here -->
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

            <!-- Table Footer -->
            <tr class="pendingApprovalsFooter">

                <!-- Footer Pagination -->
                <td width="221" class="corporateAdminPagination">
                    <a ID="bottomPageBack" class="leftArrow" runat="server" onserverclick="PageBack"></a>
                    <asp:Label ID="bottomCurrentPageInfo" Text="" runat="server" />
                    <a ID="bottomPageForward" class="rightArrow" runat="server" onserverclick="PageForward"></a>
                </td>               
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Table End -->        
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind for the above user control**

```
namespace SitefinityWebApp.userctrls.Admin.Dashboard.Corporate {
    public partial class CorpPendingApproval : System.Web.UI.UserControl {

        public int CurrentPage {
            get {
                return int.Parse(hf_currentPage.Value);
            }
            set {
                hf_currentPage.Value = value.ToString();
            }
        }
        public int TotalResults {
            get {
                return int.Parse(hf_totalResults.Value);
            }
            set {
                hf_totalResults.Value = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        //Sets default page values for pagination results
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (!IsPostBack) {
                CurrentPage = 0;
                TotalResults = GetResultSetCount();
                PopulatePageInfoTexts();
                PopulatePageWithResultSet();
            }
        }

        //Returns the count of the entire result set
        private int GetResultSetCount() {
            //Returns List<T>
            //Omitted for brevity
        }

        //Moves the pagination back one page
        protected void PageBack(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (CurrentPage > 0) {
                CurrentPage--;
                PopulatePageInfoTexts();
                PopulatePageWithResultSet();
            }
        }

        //Moves the pagination forward one page
        protected void PageForward(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (CurrentPage < (int)(TotalResults / ((CurrentPage + 1) * 20))) {
                CurrentPage++;
                PopulatePageInfoTexts();
                PopulatePageWithResultSet();
            }
        }

        //Displays info about number of results/pages for pagination
        private void PopulatePageInfoTexts() {
            //Logic omitted for brevity
        }

        //Displays result set based on current viewing page
        private void PopulatePageWithResultSet() {
            //Logic omited for brevity

            //Bind to repeaters
            TopPriority.DataSource = topPriority;
            TopPriority.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, when a pageForward or pageBack button is clicked, it changes the value in the hidden fields, and request data from DB with a new offset, and binds that data to the Repeater in the UpdatePanel.  I expect it call the server, increment the current page, and display the new results.  This only works the first time any button is clicked.  After that, the HTML is returned correctly when looking at the network calls and responses in Chrome's DevTools, but the HTML never gets re-rendered on the page after the first post back...?

There is an error that is thrown when this starts happening, and it is from jquery.cookie.js.  The include for this file is no where to be found in the entire project, so I am guessing SiteFinity includes it somewhere in one of the bundled DLLs.  I don't know if this is the root cause of the problem, but I expect it has something to do with it.  The following is the error that shows up in DevTools

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function: Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl09_TSM&compress=0&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bT…:559
_checkBrowseAndEditState:function(){browseAndEditState=jQuery.cookie(this._browseAndEditCookieName);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, jQuery Cookie plugin was needed by SiteFinity, but not listed as a resource.  Included jQuery Cookie and everything is fine.